# How to find what classes are being used by solution from a particular reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm working on converting legacy Windows .NET 4.8 application into .NET Core that will run on K8. This application depends on a particular library called `LegacyLibA` that grew into massive library over years and has code that supports other applications. I want to find out what classes from `LegacyLibA` are being used by the application I'm converting.
One way, I can accomplish this is by deleting `LegacyLibA` as references in solution/proj and seeing what errors Visual Studio will generate.
Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Do you happen to have resharper if yes https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Finding_Code_Dependent_on_Modules.html

Comment: What do you need it for? As I understand you can not recompile the library.

Comment: @Serge Slim down this library, but also because lib. has a lot of classes that aren't available in .NET CORE

Comment: @RandRandom yes, we do have a license for Resharper, but I never used it myself. Will have to ask coworkers for help. You wan to post this the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper is here to help you out.

Simply right click on a dependency and say "Find Dependent Code"

eg.

[image]

You can find further information here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Finding_Code_Dependent_on_Modules.html